# Search for the number in a cell then copy a cell from that row to another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I need to put the downstream number eg.6.25 (cell L2) into Cell L1. But this has to be found from the database. So if `Cell B1` matches anywhere in `column B` copy the L value from that row and copy to the L column in the original row i.e L1. I think that VLookup is what I am trying to do but can't make it work...

```
PIPE    17888   Upstream   Pit ID   20447   Concrete    Circular Pipe   1/04/2015   380                     6.36    img008.jpg  
PIPE    17888   Downstream Pit ID   22105   Concrete    Circular Pipe   1/04/2015   380         Downstream  6.25    img010.jpg  
PIPE    17854   Downstream Pit ID   22105   Concrete    Circular Pipe   1/04/2015   380         Downstream  6.36    img010.jpg  US PIPE NOT FOUND
PIPE    17811   Upstream   Pit ID   22105   Concrete    Circular Pipe   1/04/2015   380                     6.25    img010.jpg  
PIPE    18105   Downstream Pit ID   23037   Concrete    Circular Pipe   1/04/2015   600         Downstream  5.94    img014.jpg
```

Comment: Welcome to [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You've described your situation and supplied sample data but it would be much easier to offer a solution once we see what you've been 'really struggling with' (working or not).

Comment: well i've been looking at vlookup hlookup if functions etc i am an excel beginner and need some help this is not a classroom I don't need to justify my reasoning.

Comment: Agreed. [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) is not a classroom but neither is it a free code writing service. Good luck with your project.

Comment: VLookUp's are ideal for unique entries in a column. If you vlookup a value and it appears more than once in the range, then it will only return the selected column data from the first cell it finds. Essentially will there only be a maximum of 2 entries for each ID in column B? (1 for upstream and one for downstream)

Comment: yes shauno only a maximum of 2 entries

Answer (score 2):

IF you can be sure that "Downstream" appears once only for each ID in the B column, you could use SUMIFS, which allows multiple criteria, to find the right values to add into the appropriate cells.

```
=SUMIFS($L$2:$L$1000,$B$2:$B$1000,B2,$C$2:$C$1000,"Downstream")
```

Note the specific ID is a non-fixed cell reference - here, B2.

This wouldn't explicitly flag any problems, though; it would just evaluate to zero if no corresponding record was found and would sum the results if two or more matching records were found.

Comment: I don't need to sum the numbers Joffan. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @Jarrah, if you read Joffan's answer you'll see this is not a function that creates a SUM - It simply uses that function due to the ability to put in multiple search criteria. If you only have 1 other row with the value "Downstream" in column C and the same value in column B, this will give you what you're looking for since you'll, in essence, only be summing a single value... Nice answer, Joffan.